# `Could not open connection` issue despite using c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I've been using c3p0 for connection pooling in my Spring Boot Application for a few months now. Everything was fine until about 2 weeks ago when I started experiencing connection issues especially in the morning. Every morning when I try to log-in to my application, it would throw a `Could not open connection` error. I would then restart my application in order to remove the problem.  I am unable to figure out the root cause of the problem.

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">config.CustomDialect</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

...
POJO mappings
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here's my HibernateUtil Class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public Session openSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
}
```

I've added c3p0 debug configuration to my application to cull unreturned connections(in-case of a memory leak) and generate a stack-trace for it but nothing shows up in the logs.

Here's some of the logs from this morning :

https://pastebin.com/MGb4Miau

Can anyone here help me figure where the problem lies?

**EDIT**: `CustomDialect` Class:

```
public class CustomDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
public String getTableTypeString() {
    return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to the problem. I made the following changes to my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">10800</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">600</property>
```

And it works! The `maxIdleTime` property removes connections that have been idle from the pool for more than the specified time period(in seconds) which ensures that my connections are refreshed from time-to-time and `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections` lets me cull connections from the pool in excess of `minPoolSize` that have been idle for more than the specified time period(in seconds). This way I ensure that I don't have too many connections in the pool and that they all are fresh.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appear because you ran out of database connections.

1. too slow queries that hold the connection.
2. you have a lot of connection demands that can't fit the max pool size `100`, it is the expected cause since the problem appear after a day of running.
3. or you have source leak, because you have not close the connection after ether the transaction success or failed.

> From C3P0 logs on debug try to see how many connections are requested.

Also

Ideally, YOU must not use `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` in production, so you have to debug the connection leaks and when you have no more leaks remove 
both `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` config.

---

**Edit**

try these config:

```
<property key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Because sometimes the encoding in Hibernate is different from the encoding in MySQL db.

Comment: Ebraheem,  

I've set the `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` config in order to figure out connection leaks. So far, nothing shows up on the logs. Also, I've scanned my source code using SonarQube and no resource leaks are detected by it either. What I find surprising is that connection inactivity for upto 46,956,212 ms or ~13hr occurs despite using c3p0 and the `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` config.

Comment: and also, the last packet successfully received from the server was before about 13 hour, i want to ask at what time the app begin running

Comment: can you show the code inside `config.CustomDialect` that you have used as `hibernate.dialect` property.

Comment: I've added the `CustomDialect` class code as well @Ebraheem

Comment: try to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect` without `5`, instead of `config.CustomDialect`, and check if the problem still appear

Comment: I'll give it a try on one of my servers, but I don't think that is the answer to the problem...

Comment: that problem happens once with me, but I cann't remember how I solve it, I have tried a lot of solutions in stackoverflow before i figured it out.